# Display field from another model in ModelAdmin of User model

Tags: django

My Django project is based on built-in `User` model.

For some extra attributes, I have defined another model:

**models.py**:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    email = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

And here's the custom ModelAdmin:

**admin.py**:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = User
    list_display = ['email']
    search_fields = ['email']
```

I want `list_display` to show me `is_verified` and `is_active` fields from `Status` model but I'm lost.

I've looked into some similar questions on SO like [Display field from another model in django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71711354/display-field-from-another-model-in-django-admin) or [Add field from another model Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744301/add-field-from-another-model-django) but none of the solutions are applicable because one of my models is Django's built-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

models.py

```
class Status(models.Model):
    # email = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='status'
    )

    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

admin.py

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = User
    list_display = ['email', 'is_verified', 'is_active']
    search_fields = ['email']
    
    def is_verified(self, obj):
        return obj.status.is_verified
    
    def is_active(self, obj):
        return obj.status.is_active
```

If you want to apply the displayed name or ordering, please refer to the following
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163823/can-list-display-in-a-django-modeladmin-display-attributes-of-foreignkey-field)

---

I saw your comments and tried running the code myself. There were some problems, so I modified admin.py as follows.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

admin.site.unregister(User)


@admin.register(User)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ['email', 'status_is_verified', 'status_is_active']
    list_filter = ['status__is_verified', 'status__is_active']
    search_fields = ['email']
    
    @admin.display(ordering='status__is_verified')
    def status_is_verified(self, obj):
        return obj.status.is_verified
    
    @admin.display(ordering='status__is_active')
    def status_is_active(self, obj):
        return obj.status.is_active
```

Comment: One question: why I can use ```is_verified``` in ```list_display``` but not in ```list_filter```?

Comment: And why in admin site ```is_verified``` shows ```True/False``` instead of that green/white tick displayed for ```STAFF STATUS``` and ```SUPERUSER STATUS```?

Comment: I know the difference in how to use `list_display` and `list_filter`, but I don't know why it was made that way.

Comment: and Please read the following article for the bool type to be displayed as a geen icon. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227023/list-display-boolean-icons-for-methods